# Different output in ideone and codeblocks for same input(small factorials)

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

The following code calculates the factorial of an input integer. I ran it in Codeblocks for 2 test cases- 9 & 2 and got correct output. For the same input, ideone output factorial of 2 as 6 but it output 9 factorial correctly. What is going wrong? Also, when I make b a static array of size 200 instead of dynamic, ideone gives the right output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int t,i,j,k,temp,carry=0,len=0;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    int *b=new int;
    int *a=new int[t];
    for (i=0;i<t;i++){
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        }
    for (i=0;i<t;i++){
        len=0;
        b[0]=1;
        for (j=1;j<=a[i];j++){
            carry=0;
            for (k=0;k<=len;k++){
                temp=b[k]*j+carry;
                b[k]=temp%10;
                carry=temp/10;
                }
            while (carry!=0){
            b[++len]=carry%10;
            carry/=10;
            }
        }
        for (j=len;j>=0;j--){
            printf("%d",b[j]);
            }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int *b=new int;` -- Why are you using a pointer here?  Why not just declare an `int`?

Comment: Also, I don't understand what you're inputting into your program.  You say you input `9` and `2`, but your program shows `scanf` being called in a loop.  Why not just hard-code the data into the program, so that no one gets confused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int *b=new int;
```

allocates only one object for `b`. After that only `b[0]` or `*b` is valid. `b[k]` is not valid for values of `k` other than `0`. Hence, your program has undefined behavior.

If a static array of size 200 works, then

```
int *b=new int[200];
```

should work.

---

If the size of the array is known at compile time, I would advise using an array rather than using dynamically allocated memory. Prefer

```
int b[200];
```

over

```
int *b=new int[200];
```

Comment: Thanks, I've got it now. But is there a particular reason why static array should be preferred over dynamic?

Comment: @NikhilKaushik, There are couple of reasons to use static arrays if you can. Dynamic arrays requires more code to manage allocation and deallocation. It is more expensive to use dynamically allocated memory - the run time has to do bookkeeping work.